# Why there is a must-have tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

It is clear that questions with must-have tag will be very subjective and localized. Why there is a [must-have](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/must-have) tag?

Comment: @AlEverett I don't think this should be tagged "bug" -- it's not, plus the devs usually review bugs and it'll waste their time.

Comment: Indeed. I'll re-tag.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it was created in error. That's a meta-tag for sure.

I removed it from the two questions where it existed. The system will auto-delete it in a few days.